# How to get response header from http.get

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I get the response header from the code below? I am using the dart http package.

```
  Future<dynamic> get(String url) async {
    return _returnResponse(http.get(_location+url,headers: headers));
  }
```

Comment: check https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/get.html

Comment: @pskink yes! please make that answer so I can except it. I don't know why it was so hard to find.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to test now, but you have the `headers Map<String, String>`, and I think that with this you can get it.